# javascript: iOS audio not being loaded from page saved to Home Screen

Tags: javascript, ios, audio

page works well until being saved to Home Screen. If started from Home Screen no audio appears. The error is "Value is not a type of AudioBuffer". I guess there are problems with loading of audio with XMLHttpRequest() here. 
M4A file presents in cache.manifest, so should be cached normally.
could you please advice? Thanks

```
function beep(){
    var sound = context.createBufferSource();
    sound.buffer = soundBuffer; <<< here
    sound.connect(context.destination);
    sound.noteOn(0);
}
```

......

```
if('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
    context = new webkitAudioContext();

    function bufferSound(event) {
        var request = event.target;
        soundBuffer = context.createBuffer(request.response, false);
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'stoplight.m4a', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.addEventListener('load', bufferSound, false);
    request.send(); 
}
```

Update: solved with Base64 audio encoding. iOS doesn't cache audio files.

Comment: How are you calling beep()? Is it being called before the XMLHttpRequest has a chance to complete? What happens if you toss your beep function call inside of the your bufferSound() function body?

Comment: beep is called by onclick method for DIV. so there is enough time. m4a file is just 4kb. when accessed from web server - works fine. but not from Home Screen.

Comment: another interesting feature: it works the very first time normally. But when I close app with X in task bar and reopen it error occurs. looks like M4A isn't cached...